# Intersection of Twisted Cubic curves with hyperplanes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-varieties

The twisted cubic curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ is described as image of
the Veronese map $v: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^3$

$$v: [X_0: X_1] \mapsto [X_0^3 : X_0^2X_1 : X_0 X_1^2 : X_1^3] = [Z_0: Z_1: Z_2: Z_3]$$

Alternatively $C= v(\mathbb{P}^1)$ may be also described as zero locus of the
polynomials

$$F_0(Z) =Z_0 Z_2-Z_1^2$$

$$F_1(Z) =Z_0 Z_3-Z_1 Z_2$$

$$F_2(Z) =Z_1Z_3-Z_2^2$$

What one can show is that the intersection of $V(F_i)$ and $V(F_j)$ with $i \neq j$
is the union of a line and $C$.

**Exercise 1.12.**(from Joe Harris' Algebraic Geometry: A First Course. p 10)
Show that any finite set of points on a twisted cubic curve are
in general position, i.e., any four of them span $\mathbb{P}^3$.

One simple way to show it is to observe that every hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is
given as zero locus of linear polynomial $H= \sum_{i=0}^4 a_i Z_i$ and it suffice
to show that if we insert $X_0^3, X_0^2X_1, X_0 X_1^2, X_1^3$ in the $Z_i$ we
obtain a homogeneous polynomial of degree $3$ in $X_0, X_1$ which cannot have
more than $3$ zeroes in $\mathbb{P}^1$. So no intersection of a hyperplane in
$\mathbb{P}^3$ with $C$ hase more than $3$ points. That works.

I would like to know if it also possible to prove 1.12 directly by playing
with intersections of hyperplanes $H \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ with the $V(F_0, F_1, F_2)$.
That is can it be directly proved that if we intersect the set of solutions of
$F_0, F_1, F_2$ with any hyperplane $H=\sum_{i=0}^4 a_i Z_i$ the resulting finite set of solutions
consists at most of $3$ points?

Comment: $V(F_i)$ and $H$ have codimension $1$ in $P^3$! So the intersection is $1$-dimensional.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for correcting! They have a common component then.  Let's delete the comments if you don't mind!

Comment: What does it mean to "prove 1.12 directly by playing with intersections of hyperplanes ... with [the twisted cubic]"? Isn't that what you've already done by plugging in $X_0^3$, etc in to the $Z_i$?

Comment: It is easy to check that any intersection of three linearly independent conics (in a plane) either consists of at most three points, or is equal to a line. So, it is enough for you to check that the intersection of $V(F_i)$ does not contain a line and that no linear combination of $V(F_i)$ contains a plane.

Comment: @Sasha: Do you have a hint how to verify your first claim on the
intersection of three linearly independent conics in the plane?

Comment: If the first two conics have no common components, they intersect along a subscheme of length 4, and using the Koszul resolution of this subscheme it is easy to check that the third conic does not contain it. Thus, the intersection with the third has length at most 3. Otherwise, the first two intersect along a line and a point (possibly embedded). If the thirs does not contain the line, it intersects it along two points, so altogether the length of the intersection is at most three. The last case when all three pass through a line, then clearly there is nothing else in the intersection.

Comment: When you say that the intersection $W= V(F_1) \cap V(F_2)$ is 'subscheme
of length $4$' you mean that $W= \bigcup_i a_i \{z_i \}$ with $z_i \in P^2$
(since it's $0$-dimensional), $a_i$ are 'multiplicities' and $4= \sum a_i$, right?

Comment: A scheme structure is more than just a multiplicity. For instance, to give a scheme of length 2 supported at a point is the same as to give a tangent direction at that point.

Comment: I see, so the definition of length of the intersection subscheme
is this one:
$length(W)=\sum_{w_i\in W}\operatorname{dim}_k(\mathcal{O}_{W,w_i})$!?

Comment: The point I not understand is how do you use the
Koszyl resolution of $W =V(F_1) \cap V(F_3)$ (in the plane) here to show that this subscheme 
isn't contained in third conic $V(F_3)$. Clearly, since we assume that 
the first two conics have no common components $W$ is complete 
intersection and therefore it's Koszyl-complex is exact and therefore a resolution.
Explicitely it is given here by $0 \to S(-d_1-d_2) \xrightarrow{(F_2, -F_1)}
S(-d_1) \oplus S(-d_2) \xrightarrow{(F_1, F_2)^{T}} S \to S/I(W) \to 0$ where
$S= k[X_0,X_1, X_2]$ and $d_1, d_2$ degrees of $F_1, F_2$, ie $2$.

Comment: Ok, but how does it help to see that $W$ is *not* contained in $V(F_3)$?

Comment: It is better to write the Koszul complex in the form $$0 \to \mathcal{O}(-4) \to \mathcal{O}(-2) \oplus \mathcal{O}(-2) \to \mathcal{I}_W \to 0.$$ Twisting it by $\mathcal{O}(2)$ and using the cohomology exact sequence, one can conclude that $\dim H^0(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{I}_W(2)) = 2$, which means that there are exactly two conics through $W$.

Comment: Yes, then the last statement follows from the assumed linear independence 
of the $F_i$. Thank you, that's a nice argument!